# Postgresql Primary Key Index Maintenance

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, unique-constraint, reindex

I refresh my indexes in my Postgresql database with the "reindex index concurrently" command. However, I never renewed my primary key indexes because it might damage my primary key indexes or cause problems. My question is: Is there any harm in renewing the primary key indexes? When refreshing the indexes, I use the hours when my database is least busy, but I am hesitant to renew the primary keys. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you refresh your indexes in the first place? What problem does it solve? I did it once or twice in the last 20 years…

Comment: I check the fragmentation rate with the pgtatindex function and refresh the indexes that are above 60%.

Comment: 60% is nothing special. So what problem does the reindexing solve for you?

Comment: I do this to keep my query performance stable. To answer your question better, I need to wait for the "leaf_fregmantation" rate to reach 90% and make a comparison.

Comment: Interesting. We have never done this on our databases, with billions of records and high speed requirements. Our largest database (10TB) is now running for 12 years, started in version 9.2, migrated to version 9.5 and then to version 12. Only during these two migrations new indexes were created. Most queries run within one millisecond, 99.99% of all transactions (~400 million per day) run within 50 milliseconds. Refreshing indexes as a recurring maintenance job, is something I would never consider. Just fix the real problem, if you have one

Comment: @FrankHeikens We actually implemented this option from pgbouncer's db disconnects. We make our database connections via pgbouncer and these connections are interrupted a few times a week. As a temporary solution, I restart pgbouncer. We haven't been able to solve the source of the problem yet, we thought it might be related to the swelling of the indexes and tried this way. Currently, approximately 20 databases are connected to Pgbouncer and each of these databases has its own cluster. The resource parameters of some clusters were entered too high. Could these databases be pushing pgbouncer?

Comment: Some high parameters;
`db1: max_connections= 4096
shared_buffers= 24GB
max_prepared_transactions= 4096
work_mem= 1GB
maintenance_work_mem= 2GB`


`db2: max_connections= 4096
max_prepared_transactions= 4096
shared_buffers= 8192MB
effective_io_concurrency= 200
effective_cache_size= 24576MB
maintenance_work_mem= 2048MB
max_wal_size= 2048MB
min_wal_size= 3072MB`

In addition to these, some of my values ​​in the pgbouncer config file are;
`pool_mode = session
max_client_conn = 8192
default_pool_size = 4096
max_db_connections = 4096
server_connect_timeout = 240`

Comment: `max_connections` is pretty high, we have a large and busy database (5 million very active online customers, ~400 million transactions per day) and have this set to just 300. Most of the time we have less than 20 active connections. And do you really use prepared transactions? That is notorious slow in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Yes, we use prepared transactions, but I have never seen why the number of simultaneous connections is so high. I am thinking of setting these parameters to 500 at most. In each of the 20 clusters, these two parameters are set to 4096 and the number of active customers is far from the figures you mentioned (15 thousand). The data flow of only a few customers is in the 150-200 thousand band per day. What values ​​would you recommend for these two parameters?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder what database systems you are used to, if you are worried that rebuilding the primary key index could cause damage. It cannot cause damage.

On the other hand, it is only rarely necessary to rebuild an index. Only do that if you know it is necessary — for example, after checking for bloat with the `pgstatindex()` function.

Comment: With pgsttindex, I only renew the indexes whose leaf_fregmantation rate is above 60%. I wanted to ask because I thought that refreshing the Primary Key indexes might cause problems. Thank you for the information.

Comment: I don't think `leaf_fragmentation` is so relevant. Low `avg_leaf_density` (under 20-30%) indicates bloat.

Answer (score 0):

Because the response time in seeking into the values of an index is a logarithmic factor in relation to the number of pages used, even 50% fragmentation will have very limited or no impact on search time.

On the other hand, the fragmentation of an index significantly increases the volume of data and therefore overloads the data cache. 50% fragmentation means that the index uses double the memory space compared to a fully defragmented version. It is therefore only in the case of scanning the index values that this is of any importance...